# SAML SSO Using PingIdentity as an IDP

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to use SAML sso with pingidentiy (pingone) and componentspace SAML library.  Currently what I have to initiate the SSO is

```
 SAMLIdentityProvider.InitiateSSO(
                Response,
                "testuser", //username
                attributes,
                "https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/sso/sp/initsso?saasid=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx&idpid=xxxx",
                "PingConnect"
            );
```

When this runs it returns an error in relay state. I've figured out that I don't have a relay state to use, but I am not sure where to specify my Initiate Single Sign-On (SSO) URL from my pingone web portal (thats the sso.connect url in the code).  This is my first time doing SSO with SAML and using componentspace so I am completely lost.

I have my XML service provider setup as such

```
<PartnerServiceProvider Name="PingConnect"
        WantAuthnRequestSigned="false"
        SignSAMLResponse="true"
        SignAssertion="false"
        EncryptAssertion="false"
        AssertionConsumerServiceUrl="https://sso.connect.pingidentity.com/sso/sp/ACS.saml2"
        SingleLogoutServiceUrl="http://localhost:50839/"
        PartnerCertificateFile="sp.cer"
  SignatureMethod="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm, PingIdentity is the identity provider and your application is the service provider? Assuming so, you should be calling SAMLServiceProvider.InitiateSSO and you should have a PartnerIdentityProvider rather than a PartnerServiceProvider configuration.

Have you taken a look at the [PingOne Integration Guide](https://www.componentspace.com/Forums/5464/PingOne-Integration-Guide)? This describes both the configuration at PingOne and your application.

If you need further assistance, I suggest emailing ComponentSpace support.

Comment: I am the IDP based on what I've been told and what I've setup.  I dodn't find that guide you posted. i'll look at it. thank you

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the clarification. In many instances PingOne acts as the identity provider but it does also support external identity providers. The link I included was for PingOne acting as the identity provider not the service provider.